# Unity Help solving Uncaught Abort on HTML5 Build

Tags: c#, html, unity-game-engine

For some reason there is a Invoke that is triggered when a button is clicked that causes my game to crash. Any idea how I can sort this out?

I have plenty other Invokes and none has given problems. I have the Enable Exceptions option set to None and game works fine inside Unity.

I can give more info on the error if you can point to me to what's relevant.

```
public void OnClick()
{
    if (buyCoal.interactable == true) 
    {            
            trainObject.trainMovementStart();

            if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Level1" || SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Level2")
                Invoke("coal_refill", 6f);

            if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Level3")
                Invoke("coal_refill", 12f);

            Money.UseMoney(coalcost);
            buyCoalAudio.Play();
            countdown += 1; //agora é count up
            tipCoalReady = 2;
            buyCoalButtonIndex = 0; //DISABLE COAL Buy Button
            coal_stock_countdown.text = countdown.ToString();
            coaltipCounter += 1;                    
    }
}

void coal_refill()
{
    ThermoElectric.quota += 17.5m;
    Invoke("reactivateBuyCoalButton", 5f);
}
void reactivateBuyCoalButton()
{
    buyCoalButtonIndex = 1;
}
```

Error Log:

> Invoking error handler due to Uncaught abort(145) at Error
>     at jsStackTrace (ed63bf36d25f876fa57fb81632b59202.unityweb:8:22380)
>     at stackTrace [Object.stackTrace]   (ed63bf36d25f876fa57fb81632b59202.unityweb:8:22551)
>     at Object.onAbort (https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/html/1680115/PowerTheGrid_Level3_v7.2_HTML5/Build/3998187b7e8feaa618a93b293c0e6812.js:4:11065)

Comment: Try enabling exceptions which may give more info.